# Samsung Internet browser causing issues with font-face and svg image

Tags: svg, cross-browser, font-face, android-browser

I am having a weird problem with `@font-face` and svg images specifically on the Samsung Internet Browser on a webpage I am developing. It has some pretty strange issues.

**Part 1: The font-face problem.**

I am using 2 font-faces. For some reason in the footer area they load perfectly fine. But in other parts of the document they don't. Example:

[Image of footer area](http://minkov.mx/~misc/2015-12-01%2013.10.34.jpg)

On this image, the blockquote is displayed with the correct font, below that the Follow Us part uses the second font-face and it displays correctly too. The About Us heading uses the same font-face as the blockquote element but it doesn't display correctly. Now, the second image:

[Image of header area](http://minkov.mx/~misc/2015-12-01%2013.10.34-1.jpg)

The problem here is that the About Us huge heading uses the same font as the Follow us text in the footer area (visible in image 1), but it's not displaying correctly.

**Part 2: The SVG image problem**

In the [Image of header area](http://minkov.mx/~misc/2015-12-01%2013.10.34-1.jpg) if you focus on the upper border of the text container below About Us you can see that there's a very deformed SVG logo that says Petit Délice. If I open the image in a new tab it displays correctly, but inside the page it doesn't. I was thinking of using png substitution for browsers without svg support but from what I can see it wouldn't be of use in this case as the browser does support SVG.

Now, these two issues only occur in that specific browser and from what I've been able to check it happens in Android 4.2 and 4.4 on Samsung phones.

The site works perfectly fine on  Chrome (both Android and iOS), Firefox and on Safari, but the customer has a Samsung phone and for some reason uses the s*itty browser it has by default which is causing me severe headaches.

**You can check the site on [this link](http://www.zebradm.mx/dev/petitDelice/about-us/)**

Comment: Hi Mikhail. Did you make any progress with your issue? If not, let me know and I can follow it up (I just joined Samsung developer relations).

Comment: Hello @poshaughnessy, not really, the issue is the browser from what I've been able to deduce.

Comment: OK thanks, let me try to dig into this. So far I've checked on an S4 on Android 4.4.2 and an S7 Edge with Samsung Internet v4. I couldn't spot the issue yet. Please may I ask which device(s) you have / your customer has?

Comment: p.s. Please would you be able to share the browser version number? This might help to find that out: https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/introducing-samsung-internet-for-developers-6c3a3be42f72

Comment: Unfortunately the customer is the one with the old Samsung phone, I really hope he has updated it by now.